# Achieving constant lookup time for a KV structure where key is a predicate

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a large number of business rules that I wish to organize in a coherent manner.

These business rules roughly matches the structure of

```
When (predicate) then (action)
```

For example in Java:

```
Predicate<String> when = x -> x.equals("foo");
Supplier<String>  then = () -> "bar";

Predicate<Integer> when2 = x -> !x.equals("fizz");
Consumer<Void>     then2 = () -> System.out.println("buzz");
//etc..
```

What I am illustrating here is a list of arbitrary conditions `when` and their associated action `then`. They could take different types of value, and return something or nothing.

My first approach was to use a `HashMap` to link each of the `when` and the `then` to form a collection of rules. Then filtering it, like so:

```
ruleMap.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().test(value))
                  .findFirst()
                  .getValue();
```

The problem I have with this method is that I have to iterate through the entire collection to do so. Is there a way that I can implement in a way to achieve constant lookup time?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, but seems like an if-else condition is what you need

Comment: If else conditionals aren't O1.

Comment: @user5703 What then?

Comment: @akuzminykh the context is some collection of predicates. While a singular if else is evaluated in constant time. Finding one that within that matches within a collection is not. I am trying to find a way of finding the matching predicate at O(1).

Comment: Ok, I see. But I also don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you provide an example? Something that illustrates your problem and what you are after so we can understand better?

Comment: Should I edit the post or make a new one? I'm new here

Comment: You should edit this one. Don't worry about the downvotes, people can revert them if you edit the question and make it a nice one, which is dependent on comprehensibility in this case.

Comment: @akuzminykh edited, hopefully it is more understandable now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a constant time solution is impossible.

Comment: @user5703 Yes, it is. But I don't think you can do that in constant complexity. If there are no relations between the conditions, then it's inherently *O(n)*. If there are relations, you could e.g. organize the testing in a tree and get *O(log(n))* complexity.

Comment: @StephenC @akuzminykh One last query if I may: wouldn't the pair of `predicate` and `set of values that matches to that predicate` can form some kind of a unique key? My intuition tells me that it is a matter of crafting a key(cryptography sense) that is permissible to all elements within that set of elements that matches to that predicate

Comment: @user5703 But you have multiple predicates, which results in the complexities that I've mentioned. I understand your idea like so: You want to combine all the predicates in a single predicate. But how are you mapping the result to the effects then?

Comment: This sounds like magic to me.  Anyhow I know of know practical way of implementing this using a von Neuman architecture.  And I don't know enough about quantum computing theory to know if that would help.

Comment: Good point. O(n) it is then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you know your predicates in advance, you can pre-compute them in O(n), then look them up in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

If your key selection is an Integer (using constants, or an Enumeration with integer values in ordinal order), you can always use a dispatch table for this
(*Note:* **Untested** code - in terms of example):

```
// Note: this is a simplistic implementation of an Enum enclosing
// integer values, so that you get the idea. There might be simpler approaches
// on this, such as defining some constants, etc
public enum DispatchKeys {
    FOO(0), BAR(1);

    private final int value;
    private DispatchKeys(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getIntegerKey() {
        return key;
    }
}

Supplier<String>[] dispatcher = new Supplier<String>[] {
  () -> { return "foo"; },
  () -> { return "bar"; }
};
```

So that you then can do:

```
// O(1) selection, you practically index an array.
String result = (dispatcher[Dispatchers.FOO.getIntegerKey()])();
System.out.println(result);
```

If your keys are of another type (`String`, etc) or you plan using a comparator arrow function, It is suggested that you use a Hash Table implementation that fits your needs (e.g.,`HashMap`), which has an `O(n)` worst case complexity, but the amortized complexity is `O(1)`.